# C++ socket programming ( read() write() )

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm writing a program that transfers the contents of some files from client to server but I have some problems:

1. The number of bytes that he client writes for server is not equal to the number of bytes that the server reads.
2. Is my solution for sending the size of the files for server correct?

#### client.cpp

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std ;

const int BF_SIZE = 2048 ;

void R_directory ( int socket_id ){
    DIR *dir ;
    struct dirent *pent ;
    dir = opendir( "address of files" ) ;
    string path = "address of files" ;

    char BF_read[BF_SIZE] ;
    int n ;

    if ( dir == NULL ){
        cout << "No such directory" << endl ;
    }
    else{
        while (  pent = readdir ( dir ) ){
            if ( pent == NULL ) break ;
            if( !strcmp( pent->d_name , ".") || !strcmp ( pent->d_name , "..") ) continue ;
            string abspath = path , a ;
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < pent->d_name[i] ; i++ ) abspath.push_back( pent->d_name[i] ) ;
            FILE *fi = NULL ;
            fi = fopen ( abspath.c_str() , "r" ) ;
            struct stat fi_sp ;
            stat( abspath.c_str() , &fi_sp );
            if ( fi == NULL ){
                cout << "Can't open file " << abspath << endl ;
                continue ;
            }
            if ( fi_sp.st_size == 0 ){
                cout << "File " << abspath << " is empty" << endl ;
                continue ;
            }
            int file_size = 0 ;
            file_size = fi_sp.st_size ;
            write ( socket_id , &file_size , 4 ) ;
            cout << abspath << " " << file_size << endl ;
            while ( ( n = fread ( BF_read , 1 , BF_SIZE , fi ) ) > 0 && file_size > 0){
                cout << n << endl ;
                file_size -= n ;
                if ( file_size > 0 && n >= BF_SIZE ){
                    write ( socket_id , BF_read , sizeof ( BF_read ) ) ;
                }
                else{
                    write ( socket_id , BF_read , n - 1 ) ;
                }
            }

            cout << "=====================================" << endl ;
            fclose(fi);
        }
        int file_size = 0 ;
        write ( socket_id , &file_size , 4 ) ;
    }
    closedir(dir);
    return ;
}

int main ( int argc , char* argv[] ){
    int sockfd = 0,n = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))< 0)
    {
        cout << "Error : Could not create socket" << endl ;
        return 1;
    }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))<0)
    {
        cout << "Error : Connect Failed" << endl ;
        return 1;
    }

    R_directory( sockfd );

    return 0 ;
}
```

#### server.cpp

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std ;

const int BF_SIZE = 2048 ;

int main(void)
{
    int listenfd = 0,connfd = 0;

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    char sendBuff[BF_SIZE] , recvBuff[BF_SIZE] ;
    int numrv;

    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    printf("socket retrieve success\n");

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);

    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));

    if(listen(listenfd, 10) == -1){
        printf("Failed to listen\n");
        return -1;
    }

    connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL ,NULL);
    ofstream cout ( "output.txt" , std::ios::app ) ;

    while(1)
    {    
        int file_size = 0 , n ;
        n = read ( connfd , &file_size , 4 ) ;
        //cout << "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" << endl ;
        if ( file_size == 0 ) break ;
        while ( file_size > 0 ){
            n = read( connfd , recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff) ) ;
            cout << n << endl ;
            if ( n == 0 ) break ;
            file_size -= n ;
            /*for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ){
                cout << recvBuff[i] ;
            }*/
        }
        cout << endl ;
    }
    close(connfd);

    return 0;
}
```

In client side, the number of bytes that I send is equal to file size in bytes but in server I got more bytes — why?

Comment: Do you have problems with different endianess on client/server?

Comment: no i haven't , i checked that

Comment: 1) Because any number of writes can result in any number of reads. If you think that each write will be one read, that´s just wrong. All written bytes == All read bytes (with TCP at least, and only while the connection is open on both sides), but where the messages are "cut" in pieces is not guarenteed.

Comment: Though it would be better and portable style to transfer the data size information in network byte order.

Comment: @deviantfan , actually in my program i want send contents of different files , and i need a method to recognize when i got a file completely in server side , do you have any solutions ?

Comment: @Reza Don´t just send the file content, but some length etc. first so that you know where the file ends? And put your send/recv in a loop.

Comment: @deviantfan , i think you don't see my code :D , first i sent my file length in byte and in server i receive bytes until i got all bytes that i send first , but it doesn't work and i got more byte in server . i use while for read and write

Comment: You need to limit the file read size on the final read. You can use an expression like `MIN(sizeof buffer, remaining)`.

Comment: @EJP , thank you so much . i changed this  n = read( connfd , recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff) ) ; to n = read( connfd , recvBuff, min ( sizeof(recvBuff) , (long unsigned int )file_size ) ) ; and now it work .